# How to video slider auto play when first one is finish

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a video slider , can any one help me to solve my problem,
I want to auto play slider, after one finish play next and pause on hover.
I have attached the code
...

```
var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo"); 
var vid2 = document.getElementById("myVideo2"); 
var vid3 = document.getElementById("myVideo3"); 


var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
    vid.pause();
    vid2.pause();
    vid3.pause();
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";

}

////playbutton///
$(".play-button").on("click", function () {
  $(this).hide();
  $(this).parent().fadeOut();
  $(this).parent().siblings(".slider-video")[0].play();
});

$(".slider-video").on("play", function () {
  $(this).attr("controls", "1");
});
```

..

https://codepen.io/uiswarup/pen/Vwevvbr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution.
Just update the way we handle play, pause, ended events.
And use another way to manage slide.

```js
playVideo = function (video) {
    if (video && video.length) {
      video[0].play();
      video[0].controls = true;
    }
  }

  var slider = $('.slideshow-container');
  var setActiveSlide = function (slideIndex, autoplay) {
    const activeSlide = slider.find('.mySlides').eq(slideIndex);
    if (!activeSlide) return;
    activeSlideIndex = slideIndex;
    slider.find('.mySlides').hide(); // hide all slides
    activeSlide.show(); // display active slide
    $('.bullets').find('.dot').removeClass('active');
    $('.bullets').find('.dot').eq(slideIndex).addClass('active');

    // Pause all video
    slider.find('video').each(function(elemIndex, elem  ) {
      elem.pause();
    });
    if (autoplay) {
      playVideo(activeSlide.find('video'));
    }
  };
  var activeSlideIndex = 0;
  setActiveSlide(activeSlideIndex);

  var toNextSlide = function(autoplay) {
    // Return if last slide
    if (activeSlideIndex >= slider.find('.mySlides').length) return;
    setActiveSlide(activeSlideIndex + 1, autoplay);
  }
  var toPrevSlide = function() {
    // Return if first slide
    if (activeSlideIndex === 0) return;
    setActiveSlide(activeSlideIndex -1);
  }
  
  // ADD EVENT LISTENERS
  $('.play-button').on('click', function(e) {
    var video = $(e.target).parents('.slideVideo').find('video');
    playVideo(video);
  })

  $('video').on('play', function(e) {
    $(e.target).parents('.slideVideo').addClass('playing');
  });
  $('video').on('pause', function(e) {
    $(e.target).parents('.slideVideo').removeClass('playing');
  });

  $('video').on('ended', function(e) {
    toNextSlide(true);
  });
```

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box}
body {font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; margin:0}
.mySlides {display: none}
img {vertical-align: middle;}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -22px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

/* Caption text */
.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .prev, .next,.text {font-size: 11px}
}




.sliderVideo {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 20px 20px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 10px 10px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04) !important;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 20px 20px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 10px 10px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04) !important;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 20px 20px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 10px 10px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04) !important;
    -ms-box-shadow: 0 20px 20px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 10px 10px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04) !important;
    -o-box-shadow: 0 20px 20px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 10px 10px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04) !important;
}


.slide_group_video {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.slideVideo {
}

.slideVideo:first-child {
  display: block;
}

.slideVideo:nth-of-type(1) {
background-color:black;
  
}

.slideVideo:nth-of-type(2) {
  background-color:black;
}

.slideVideo:nth-of-type(3) {
   background-color:black;
}

.slideVideo:nth-of-type(4) {
 background-color:black;
}

.slideVideo_buttons {
position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    bottom: 21%;
    z-index: 10;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
    box-shadow: 0 20px 20px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 10px 10px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04) !important;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 20px 20px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 10px 10px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04) !important;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 20px 20px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 10px 10px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04) !important;
    -ms-box-shadow: 0 20px 20px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 10px 10px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04) !important;
    -o-box-shadow: 0 20px 20px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 10px 10px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04) !important;
}

a.slidevideo_btn {
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 42px;
  margin: 0 0.175em;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.slidevideo_btn.active, .slidevideo_btn:hover {
  color: #04fffd;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.directional_nav {
  height: 340px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 940px;
  position: relative;
  top: -340px;
}

.previousVideo_btn {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 10%;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.nextVideo_btn {
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10%;
  top: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.previousVideo_btn, .nextVideo_btn {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 45px;
  opacity: 0.5;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
  width: 65px;
}

.previousVideo_btn:hover, .nextVideo_btn:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .previousVideo_btn {
    left: 10%;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .nextVideo_btn {
    right: 10%;
    text-align: center;
  }
}


.play-button {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 4em;
    height: 3em;
    margin-top: -1.5em;
    margin-left: -2em;
    background: red;
    border-radius: 1em;
    cursor: pointer;
  text-align:center;
}
.play-button:after {
    content:"\25b6";
    font-size: 2em;
    line-height: 1.4em;
}
video{
       max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.overlay-content {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: 0.4s opacity;
}

.text {
  display: none;
}

.slideVideo.playing .overlay-content {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slideshow-container">

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
  <div class="sliderVideo">
    <div class="slideVideo">

                        <video controls id="myVideo" class="slider-video" poster="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/1724357/placecard_jetblue.jpg">
                            <source src="https://www.learningcontainer.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/sample-mp4-file.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
                            <source src="https://www.learningcontainer.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/sample-mp4-file.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
                            <source src="https://www.learningcontainer.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/sample-mp4-file.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
                        </video>
                        <div class="overlay-content">
                            <div class="play-button"></div>
                        </div>


                    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
   <div class="sliderVideo">
    <div class="slideVideo">

                        <video id="myVideo2" class="slider-video" poster="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/1724357/placecard_jetblue.jpg">
                            <source src="https://www.learningcontainer.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/sample-mp4-file.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
                            <source src="https://www.learningcontainer.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/sample-mp4-file.mp4" type="video/webm" />
                            <source src="https://www.learningcontainer.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/sample-mp4-file.mp4" type="video/ogg" />
                        </video>
                        <div class="overlay-content">
                            <div class="play-button"></div>
                        </div>


                    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="text">Caption Two</div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
   <div class="sliderVideo">
    <div class="slideVideo">

                        <video id="myVideo3" class="slider-video" poster="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/1724357/placecard_jetblue.jpg">
                            <source src="https://www.learningcontainer.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/sample-mp4-file.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
                            <source src="https://www.learningcontainer.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/sample-mp4-file.mp4" type="video/webm" />
                            <source src="https://www.learningcontainer.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/sample-mp4-file.mp4" type="video/ogg" />
                        </video>
                        <div class="overlay-content">
                            <div class="play-button"></div>
                        </div>


                    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
</div>

<a class="prev" onclick="toPrevSlide()">&#10094;</a>
<a class="next" onclick="toNextSlide()">&#10095;</a>

</div>
<br>

<div class="bullets" style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot" onclick="setActiveSlide(0)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="setActiveSlide(1)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="setActiveSlide(2)"></span> 
</div>
```

Comment: Its Working fine now, need little changes to pause the video on hover , I will do that, Many thanks to you.

Comment: Can you please suggest me the code change to auto play the first video on page load
@chuong tran

Comment: @SwarupKumar
I create a function for changing the slide (`setActiveSlide`) with 2 inputs, the last one is for autoplaying the video in slide.
And when page load, i call setActiveSlide(0, true). to make first slide as default and also play the video in it.

Comment: You can try with `window.onload = function () { // Initial slider here }`

Answer (score 0):

This is an idea. I don´t know how to slider is working.

```
             //I assumed that all video tag have class .slider-video
            var allVideos = $(".slider-video");
            var countVideos = allVideos.length;
            var currentIndex = -1;
            allVideos.on("ended", function (evt) {
                currentIndex++;
                if (currentIndex > countVideos - 1) {
                    currentIndex = 0;
                } else {
                    //Auto Play next video.
                    allVideos[currentIndex].get(0).play();
                }
            });
            allVideos.on("play", function (evt) {
                currentIndex = allVideos.index(this);
            });
            allVideos.on("playing", function (evt) {
                currentIndex = allVideos.index(this);
                var v = $(this).get(0);
                v.controls = false;
            });
            //PREVENT CONTEXT MENU.
            allVideos.on("contextmenu", function (evt) {
                return false;
            });
            allVideos.on("mouseover", function (evt) {
                currentIndex = allVideos.index(this);
                var v = $(this).get(0);
                v.pause();
                v.controls = true;
            });
            allVideos.on("mouseout", function (evt) {
                currentIndex = allVideos.index(this);
                var v = $(this).get(0);
                v.play();
                v.controls = false;
            });
```

Comment: `.bind()` is long time deprecated (as of jQuery 3.0) in favor of `.on()`...

Comment: Also, `$(this).index()` might not give you the desired index. You should use `$all.index(this)` where `$all` is a specific collection... That's really basic jQuery stuff.